# What are the applications of Knuth/Fisher-yates algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knuth, fisher-yates-shuffle

This algorithm guarantees to rearrange the elements in uniformly random order. What does uniformly random mean ?

Comment: Do you want to ask about the applications of this algorithm, or the definition of "uniformly random"? Those are two separate questions. Did you try searching for answers to either of them?

Comment: @kaya3 Actually I wanted to know both...I searched for it.. I got a basic idea..but I want to know more applications..

Comment: Every time you draw from the deck, you're equally likely to draw each card that you haven't drawn yet.

Comment: @David Eisenstat thank you..that cleared so many doubts..